# Timescaledb update FATAL: extension "timescaledb" version mismatch: shared library version 1.6.1; SQL version 1.4.2

Tags: timescaledb

Server has 3  databases with timescaledb
2 updated well
but 3 have error

```
psql -p 5433 -X -d rates
rates=# ALTER EXTENSION timescaledb UPDATE;
ERROR:  extension "timescaledb" version mismatch: shared library version 1.6.1; SQL version 1.4.2
CONTEXT:  parallel worker
```

show version tsdb on current database

```
SELECT default_version, installed_version FROM pg_available_extensions WHERE name = 'timescaledb';

 default_version | installed_version
-----------------+-------------------
 1.6.1           | 1.4.2
```

Comment: How do you connect to server? Do you connect remotely? Can it be that you are calling `psql` from local installation, which contains different version to TimescaleDB?

Comment: connected from localhost

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Then it is not related to the case I thought. Have you tried just restart the cluster (e.g., `pg_ctl restart`), i.e., without modifying the PostgreSQL config?

Answer (score 1):

```
max_parallel_workers = 0
```

in postgresql.conf and reload config postgresq;

Answer (score 0):

According to the release notes of 1.5.0 version, which is on the update path between 1.4.2 and 1.6.1, it is necessary to restart the instance before doing the update. From [the release notes](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/releases/tag/1.5.0):

> For this release only, you will need to restart the database before running
> ALTER EXTENSION.